# WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:52312/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

Tags: html, sockets, websocket

I am trying to implement a simple HTML5 WebSocket, But the connection is simply not getting established & I am getting below error as WebSocket object is created

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:52312/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

Below is the code

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
        function runHub() {
            if ("WebSocket" in window) {

                console.log('WebSocket is supported by your browser.');

                //var serviceUrl = 'ws://localhost:52312/';
                var serviceUrl = 'ws://localhost:52312/home/GetNotificationCount';

                var protocol = 'Chat-1.0';
                var socket = new WebSocket(serviceUrl);

                socket.onopen = function () {
                    console.log('Connection Established!');
                };

                socket.onclose = function (error) {
                    console.log('Connection Closed!');
                    console.log('Error Occured: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
                };

                socket.onerror = function (error) {
                    console.log('Error Occured: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
                };

                socket.onmessage = function (e) {
                    if (typeof e.data === "string") {
                        console.log('String message received: ' + e.data);
                    }
                    else if (e.data instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
                        console.log('ArrayBuffer received: ' + e.data);
                    }
                    else if (e.data instanceof Blob) {
                        console.log('Blob received: ' + e.data);
                    }
                };


                if (!socket.readyState === WebSocket.CLOSED) {
                    socket.send($('#notificationCount').text);
                    //socket.close();

                }

            }
        }

        var run = setInterval(function () {
            runHub();
        }, 10000)
    });
```

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: what are you connecting to? looks like you're not connecting to something that wants a websocket connection, like a plain webserver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-4.1

> Once the client's opening handshake has been sent, the client MUST
> wait for a response from the server before sending any further data.
> The client MUST validate the server's response as follows:

> 1. If the status code received from the server is not 101, the
>    client handles the response per HTTP [RFC2616] procedures.  In
>    particular, the client might perform authentication if it
>    receives a 401 status code; the server might redirect the client
>    using a 3xx status code (but clients are not required to follow
>    them), etc.  Otherwise, proceed as follows.

Section 4.2.2 elaborates: apart from responding with code 101 and appropriate headers, server may ask for authenication (response code 401), may redirect (3xx codes), and should perform TLS handshake if you attempt to establish a secure connection (if you use `wss://` protocol).

The server located at `localhost:52312` responded with code 200 - websocket standard, as you see above, doesn't define any sense in this response. So a client is in it's right to raise an exception. The problem is in the server.